# NSString type declaration

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm studying Objective-C. Can you tell me what is the difference (if any) between these NSString declarations?

```
NSString *firstString;
firstString = @"First string";

NSString *secondString = [NSString string];
secondString = @"Second string";
```

Answer (score 8):

The second one creates two strings, and throws the first one away without using it. In this line:

```
NSString *secondString = [NSString string];
```

you are creating a new string, which isn't really useful because it's empty, and you're assigning it to `secondString`. Then you're assigning a *different* string (`@"Second String"`) to `secondString`.

There's no need to do this. In either case, you can just write:

```
NSString *myString = @"MyString";
```

---

The syntax `@"Some string here"` is called a *string literal*, and it's a shorthand for specifying an NSString with an actual value in your code.

Answer (score 1):

No difference as the end result.

The first string is being declared and then assigned a value via the string literal syntax (you can also do this with `NSNumbers` as of Xcode 4.4).

The second is being initialised as a string (empty) and then is being assigned another NSString object. In this case there are actually two NSString objects being created, the former - `[NSString string]` is being overwritten by the latter `@"string value"`

So, the first one is `nil` to start with and then has a value. The second had a instantiated `NSString` object to start and was then overwritten.

In the end both string objects are the same, but obviously you are wasting resources in the second case.